# Items appear in front of relative layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am adding a relative layout and items appear in front of it, I can even select them even though I put my relative layout at the end of the XML.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scaleType="center"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
tools:context="julienkessels.com.daredrink.SettingsActivity">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/backgroundpaperr"
    android:alpha="0.45"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnHome"
    android:layout_width="70sp"
    android:layout_height="60sp"
    android:src="@drawable/home"
    android:background="@drawable/home"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />

<TextView
    android:text="Remove Ads :"
    android:layout_width="300sp"
    android:layout_height="40sp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnRemoveAdss"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100sp"
    android:id="@+id/txtRemoveAds" />

<Button
    android:text=""
    android:layout_width="200sp"
    android:layout_height="100sp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/btnRemoveAdss"
    android:src="@drawable/newremoveads"
    android:background="@drawable/newremoveads"        />

<TextView
    android:text="Add your own rules :"
    android:layout_width="300sp"
    android:layout_height="40sp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnAddRule"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100sp"
    android:id="@+id/txtAddRule" />

<Button
    android:text=""
    android:layout_width="200sp"
    android:layout_height="100sp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
    android:id="@+id/btnAddRule"
    android:src="@drawable/house"
    android:background="@drawable/house"
    />
<TextView
    android:text="Choose your language :"
    android:layout_width="300sp"
    android:layout_height="40sp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/spinnerLanguageSettings"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40sp"
    android:id="@+id/txtLanguageSpinner" />
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerLanguageSettings"
    android:popupBackground="#cccccc"
    android:popupTheme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="420dp"
    android:background="@drawable/spinnerbg" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alpha="1"
    android:id="@+id/subViewOwnRules"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    tools:alpha="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:src="@drawable/subview1"
        android:alpha="0.9"
        tools:alpha="0.9" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBack"
        android:layout_width="150sp"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:src="@drawable/next"
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I can't find any explanation on the Internet. This is how it currently looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tnm3Z.png

Ads and HouseRules buttons should be below the subview, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the your RelativeLayout so it can receive click events.

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Comment: Didnt' work. The buttons visible on the relativeLayout shouldnt be visible because the relativelayout doesnt contain the buttons and the buttons are behind the layout